# What are the best "session" variables to use with react and react router version 6.4?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, variables, session-variables

Newbie just getting started with react & react router version 6.4. I am working with building a multi page solution and trying to understand the various variable storage to use such as local, session, global variables - also javascript Window localStorage & sessionStorage etc.

In previous PHP Solutions I extensively used session variables to store the user and invoice or project variables throughout the solution.

I am trying to learn about the various react hooks related to variable storage/usage and I am a bit confused between them such as: params, context, props etc.

Can someone help explain how these hooks compare to local - session - global variables?

As an example, let's say I have a user login and work with a shopping cart. Using "PHP session variables" concept - I could store the user login info and the various shopping cart variables such as an invoice ID and product id's etc. Then I could go to various separate pages and reference those variables easily. Is there a way to do this with react?

In react, I found myself working on a page and I was able to access a react hook: useParams in my main function but lower on the page I created a second function and it was unable to use the useParams variables. (Someone said now I needed to create custom hooks for this purpose?) Is there a way to create a "session" variable that can be used across multiple pages?

Q: thinking like what's possible in PHP, is there a way to declare some kind of react hook "session" variable or something else that can be used in a react project?

Thanks Dave

Update: Ex: let's say I was building a simple todo app that had various categories and the related child items. The general idea would be to click on a category - and then see a list of the available child items - and another list grandchild sub items.

So in this use case - it would be good to Store the category ID in some sort of "session variable" that could be reused when working with the various child items and possibly grandchild sub items.

For this very simple purpose what do you recommend to Store the category ID? Is this a good use for react context or is there a better "react place - hook" to Store the category ID?

Comment: *Is there a way to create a "session" variable that can be used across multiple pages?* - react context + `useState` is what you need probably. I wouldn't learn React based on php experience. It's better to start over

Comment: Thanks Konrad for your response. Am I correct in assuming that react context is good for storing more like global variables, where they do not change often?